# Is there a way in tensorflow(<2) to use a dynamic input shape with a frozen graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I got a two-part question here. First of all, is it possible to use a dynamic(variable) shape input (image) with a frozen graph? More exactly:

```py
    graph = unfreeze(output_graph) #this unfreezes a .pb model. I can add that as well if necessary 

    x = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/Placeholder:0')
    y = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/generator/out:0')

    with tf.Session(config=config, graph=graph) as sess:

        #some irrelevant code related to 'image'
        image_out = sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: image})
```

This throws a very understandable error about how to size of the image doesn't fit what the placeholder is expecting. (if indeed it doesn't fit)

**This leads me to the second part of my question:**
If I use a model that I restore from a checkpoint (graph from chkp.meta, variables from .data), I can somehow, magically, choose the size of the input tensor like so:

```py
#IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH are just the shape of the images I'm doing prediction on, regardless of the training input shape

    x_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, IMAGE_SIZE])
    x_image = tf.reshape(x_, [-1, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, 3])
#more stuff.. 
    out = sess.run(y, feed_dict={x_: image})
```

**In conclusion**, what I'm really asking is how is it possible to choose the input shape after the training? shouldn't that be fixed ? even if the variables are still ***variable*** and not ***constant*** as they are in the frozen model, they should still have the same shape and number. It makes no sense to me to be able to modify the shape of the layers after training.

Thanks and sorry if I didn't abide the posting rules, it's my first time.